# How to use Spark from_csv function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Apache Spark to receive messages from Kafka that contains CSV as strings. To convert a CSV string into a Spark DataFrame, I read that `from_csv` function is the solution. So, when I receive a message from Kafka, it goes into the column `value` of my DataFrame. The CSV string looks like this:

`uid,datetime,quality\nfcc5382b-201b-4c10-9db9-e5de7f8c1d32,2023-07-04 11:32:24,passed\n`

(This is test data, no sensitive data here)

I was expecting this:

```
[Row(csv=Row(uid='fcc5382b-201b-4c10-9db9-e5de7f8c1d32', datetime=datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 11, 32, 24), quality='passed'))]
```

But instead, I got this:

```
[Row(csv=Row(uid='uid', datetime=None, quality='quality\nfcc5382b-201b-4c10-9db9-e5de7f8c1d32'))]
```

I looked at the doc of [from_csv function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_csv.html) and [data source options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) but nothing worked.

Here is my code to recreate the issue:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_csv
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType
 
# Setting up Spark
appName = "Trying to extract CSV from string"
masterName = "local"
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName(
    name=appName
).master(
    master=masterName
)
spark = builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
# Recreating DataFrame
csvString = [("uid,datetime,quality\nfcc5382b-201b-4c10-9db9-e5de7f8c1d32,2023-07-04 11:32:24,passed\n",)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(csvString, ("value",))
 
# Defining my csv data schema
csvSchema = StructType([
    StructField("uid", StringType()),
    StructField("datetime", TimestampType()),
    StructField("quality", StringType())
])
 
# Defining my options
options = {
    'header': True,
    'lineSep': '\n'
}
 
# Applying function
df.select(
    from_csv(
        df.value,
        csvSchema.simpleString(),
        options=options
    ).alias(
        "csv"
    )
).collect()
```

Spark version: 3.4.1

Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: if you replace `StructField("datetime", TimestampType()),` with `StructField("datetime", StringType()),`, it "works" and you see that it only takes the "first" line which is the header line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is that `\n` is not accepted as a line separator.

Digging into the spark code I noticed this separator was disabled actually in 3.2.2+ (actually replaced by a unicode Noncharacters `\UFFFF`). Here is the ticket describing why : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38955

I agree, the documentation doesn't seem to be up-to-date... But basically we don't expect to use one line containing all the csv content, so you can't rely on the separators.

Something like that should work though :

```
csvString = [("fcc5382b-201b-4c10-9db9-e5de7f8c1d32,2023-07-04 11:32:24,passed",),("dummyId,2022-01-01 11:32:24,failed",)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(csvString, ["value",])

df.show()
df.printSchema()
 
# Defining my csv data schema
csvSchema = StructType([
    StructField("uid", StringType()),
    StructField("datetime", TimestampType()),
    StructField("quality", StringType())
])
 
df.select(from_csv(df.value, csvSchema.simpleString()).alias("csv")).collect()
```

As @Steven mentioned, you could also maybe use a `split` function with `explode` to basically mimic the line separator option then apply the `from_csv`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: maybe use a `split` function with `explode` then apply the `from_csv`

Comment: @Steven good point I'll add that to the answer